# Character does not show in XSLT

Tags: xslt

In XSLT performed a **normalize-space** and not done well, it's not a **whitespace** is a character invisible.

**Element**

```
<div class='tyreNameComplete'> WinterContact TS800 </div>
```

**XSLT:**

```
translate(//x:div[@class='tyreNameComplete'], ' ', '')
```

**the element with strange characters:**

```
&#10;            WinterContact TS800 &#10;            &#10;            &#10;                &#10;                    &#10;                    &#10;                &#10;                &#10;            &#10;
```

The character is: `&#10;` no show.

**I hope the result is:**

```
WinterContact TS800
```

I need to clean to get only what you need. How would you treat this case?. Thanks.

**The solution:**

```
translate(//x:div[@class='tyreNameComplete'], '&#10; ', '')
```

contain invisible character after `&#10;`, to view visualize the file in linux terminal and copy the character in my xslt.

Comment: `&#10;` is a linefeed character, which is whitespace. `normalize-space()` will collapse it to a single space. Why do you want to keep it? Most importantly edit your question to **show exactly what is your desired output.**

Comment: like it removed, and leaving only the text, but the normalize-space() does not eliminate it, and translate() either.

Comment: Show the complete XSLT template. With your updated question I am almost certain that the whitespace is being introduced by your XSLT code, *not* the source XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this source XML:

```
<element>&#10;            WinterContact TS800 &#10;            &#10;            &#10;                &#10;                    &#10;                    &#10;                &#10;                &#10;            &#10;        </element>
```

And this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <collapsed><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(element)"/></collapsed>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this output:

```
<collapsed>WinterContact TS800</collapsed>
```

This appears to be what you want?

Comment: The result, source code shows this:

    <collapse>&#10;WinterContactTS800 &#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;</collapse>

Comment: Then your source xml is literally `&amp;#10;`? I.e. the element content was double-escaped at some point?